# angular 2 template doesnt recognize template reference variables

Tags: javascript, angular, templates

I am working on building a site with Angular 2 and am having some problems with template reference variables.  I am creating a pretty straightforward form to add a new listing to an online store:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="productSKU">Product SKU</label>
    <input #productSKU type="text" class="form-control" id="productSKU" placeholder="Enter Product SKU">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="productTitle">Product Title</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="productTitle" placeholder="Enter Product Title" #productTitle>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="productSubtitle">Product Subtitle</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="productSubtitle" placeholder="Enter Product Subtitle" #productSubtitle>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="productPrice">Product Price (USD)</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="productPrice" placeholder="Enter Product Price" #productPrice>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="productType">Select Product Type</label>
    <select multiple class="form-control" id="productType" #productType>
      <option *ngFor="let type of listingTypes" [value]="type">{{type}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="productDescription">Product Description</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" id="productDescription" rows="8" #productDescription></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="productCondition">Product Condition</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="productCondition" placeholder="Enter Product Condition" #productCondition>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="storageLocation">Storage Location</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="storageLocation" placeholder="Enter Storage Location" #storageLocation>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="image1Path">Image 1</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="image1Path" id="image1Path" placeholder="Enter Image 1 File Name" #image1Path>
  </div>
  <button class="btn" id="newPostSubmitButton" (click)="onNewListingSubmit(productTitle.value,
                                                                            productSubtitle.value,
                                                                            productType.value,
                                                                            productPrice.value,
                                                                            productDescription.value,
                                                                            productCondition.value,
                                                                            productSKU.value,
                                                                            storageLocation.value,
                                                                            image1Path.value)">Submit</button>
</div>
```

For some reason when I try to trigger the onNewListingSubmit method in the component on the submit button click, it is giving me the following error:

[image: error example]

As you can see, it can't find the property "value" of undefined.  It seems to not be recognizing the various template reference variables throughout the form (e.g. #productSKU, #productPrice, etc.)

Any ideas why this might be happening?  Can't seem to find any other examples of the same problem.  Thanks

Comment: For which one? Try to remove one by one to see on what it throws error. If for all, you can achieve the same result with `ngModels`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `productCondition` is not defined on template.

Comment: Indeed, quite confusing, because `ViewChild` for example will inject `ElementRef`.

Comment: I just noticed the productCondition problem, but I added it and am still receiving the same error.

Comment: I also changed the ref.value for each to ref.nativeElement.value (as suggested earlier).  The linter is no longer complaining but it is still throwing the same error in the browser. Ugh.

Comment: It should work, see https://plnkr.co/edit/IWLDD2uDWOTR2dJ8hTHw?p=preview

Comment: What exactly am I supposed to be looking at here?

Comment: `App.ts` contains the same code as you have provided and it just works.

Comment: Could it be because I am using a separate template file and not putting the template directly in the component file?

Comment: Make sure your template is updated and app is recompiled. If it still fails then error is in the code that you did not provide and you have to follow @ Suren Srapyan advice.

Answer (score 0):

Since you use `textarea` element. There's no direct property `value` in `textarea`. At least its value defined for the collection of elements in `textarea`.